# Partitions of unity in general topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $C(X)$ be the set of continuous functions on $X$.

**Step 1.** If a finite set $F\subset C(X)$ and $\varepsilon>0$ are given, then we can find a finite open cover $\{U_{1},...,U_{n}\}$ of $X$ with the property that for each $f\in F$ and $1\leq i\leq n$, we have 
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$$
for any pair of points $x, y\in U_{i}$.

**Step 2.** Let $y_{i}\in U_{i}$ be arbitrarily chosen and $\{\sigma_{1}, ...,\sigma_{n}\}$ be a partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{U_{1},...,U_{n}\}$.

My question are

1. In the step 1, how to find a finite open cover $\{U_{1},...,U_{n}\}$ of $X$ with such a property above?
2. In the step 2, what is meaning of a patition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{U_{1},...,U_{n}\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Step 1**, consider the family $(U_x)_{x\in X}$ of open sets defined by
$$
U_x = \bigcap_{f\in F} f^{-1}\left[B_{\varepsilon/2} (f(x))\right],
$$
where $B_{\varepsilon/2}(f(x)) = \{\,z\in\mathbb C\mid \left|z-f(x)\right|<\varepsilon/2\,\}$ is the open ball of radius $\varepsilon/2$ centered at $f(x)$.

For all $f\in F$ and $x,y\in U_{x_0}$ we have $f(x),f(y)\in B_{\varepsilon/2} (f(x))$, thus
$$
\left|f(x) - f(y)\right| \le \left|f(x_0)-f(x)\right|+\left|f(x_0)-f(y)\right| < \frac\varepsilon 2+\frac\varepsilon 2=\varepsilon.
$$
Since $X$ is compact, pick a finite subcover.

In **Step 2** a partition of unity subordinate to the cover $\{U_1,\dots,U_n\}$ is a family of $n$ continuous functions $\sigma_i:X\to [0,1]$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \sigma_i \subseteq U_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i(x)=1$ for all $x\in X$. Here $\operatorname{supp}(f) = \{\,x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0\,\}$ is the support of $f$.

Comment: Well, if C(X) be the set of continuous functions from X to $\mathbb{C}$ (not $\mathbb{R}$), what is the partition of unity subordinate to the cover $U_{1},...U_{n}$?

Comment: @Belle-tiantian I changed my definition of $U_x$ to work for $\mathbb C$-valued functions. The definition of a partition of unity always uses functions to $[0,1]$.

Comment: So the $\sigma_{i}$ is a continuous function from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: @Belle-tiantian Yes, we could say it is a continuous function $X\to\mathbb R$ with $0\le \sigma(x)\le 1$ for all $x\in X$. That gives the same definition of partition of unity as taking continuous functions $X\to [0,1]$.

Comment: Oh~ yes, thanks Christoph.